# UncaughtExceptionHandler and System.exit()

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown-hook

I've written a custom UncaughtExceptionHandler that should print the exception to the console and shut down the application with a custom exit code.

The class looks like this:

```
public class FatalUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(final Thread t, final Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Handled exception in " + t.getName() + ":");

        e.printStackTrace();

        System.exit(ExitCodes.UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

---

I set the UncaughtExceptionHandler in my Main.class like this:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new FatalUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

Then I generate and start 4 threads.

In one of the running threads I purposely generate a `NumberFormatException` using `Integer.valueOf("Test")` in order to test my Handler. This works fine; Here's the output:

```
Handled exception in WatchdogThread:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Test"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at com.csg.gfms.gms.ctmgate.runnable.WatchdogThread.run(WatchdogThread.java:43)
```

---

Now I  have a problem. For some reason the thread in which the exception was thrown is not being shutdown by the System.exit() command. Apparently my ShutdownHook has a lock on it. (As seen in the output of jvisualvm):

```
"WatchdogThread" #38 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001efa3800 nid=0xd40 in Object.wait() [0x0000000021a5e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000076e30a7c0> (a com.csg.gfms.gms.ctmgate.runnable.CTMShutdownHook)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
        - locked <0x000000076e30a7c0> (a com.csg.gfms.gms.ctmgate.runnable.CTMShutdownHook)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
        at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:107)
        at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:167)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
        - locked <0x00000006c9605b00> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:109)
        at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:971)
        at com.csg.gfms.gms.ctmgate.handlers.FatalUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(FatalUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:13)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1959
```

Even IntelliJ tells me that the System.exit command will fail. It displays a little badge next to it saying "Method will fail" when debugging my UncaughtExceptionHandler.

---

This leads me to my question:

**Is it not allowed to call System.exit() from an UncaughtExceptionHandler?**

**Is the shutdown hook initiated twice in my case?**

**What could be the reason for the lock on the shutdown hook?**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Calling System.exit from anywhere is usually discouraged. It is an abrupt way to end a program. Another thread could be in the middle of doing work and have it lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that `com.csg.gfms` stuff in the trace?

It's not java; it's you. That's your code that's blocking in another shutdown hook; one that is calling `Thread.join`.

Generally when running into such weirdness, if it is at all possible to make a stand-alone super simple test case, then you should do so. I have done this for you:

```
class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                                System.out.println("EXITING");
                                System.exit(1);
                        }
                });
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                        try {
                                                Thread.sleep(1000L);
                                        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
                                        throw new RuntimeException();
                                }
                        });
                        t.start();
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
                System.out.println("Still alive?");
        }
}
```

When I run this, I get an arbitrary number of `EXITING` prints (2 to 3, it's dependent on how many cores are simultaneously working on these threads), and then the VM hard-exits. `Still alive?` is never printed, no locking occurs, the VM actually exits.

Thus proving that calling `System.exit()` from within the uncaught exception handler is not an issue.

The shutdown hook is not invoked twice; the shutdown hook is invoked due to you invoking `System.exit`, not because we got to the uncaught exception handler. But, if you're worried about this, hey, it's your app, print something in your shutdown hooks to be sure.

The lock issue is not on *the* shutdown hook. You can register any amount of shutdown hooks. It's in *a* shutdown hook. Specifically: somebody registered an instance of `com.csg.gfms.gms.ctmgate.runnable.CTMShutdownHook`, that code is joining some thread, and that thread is not shutting down, thus that hook never exits, thus System.exit is not exiting the VM. **The solution is to fix CTMShutdownHook, which is broken**.

Joining a thread in a shutdown hook is... well, I'll just say it bluntly: Stupid. I don't quite know what this is trying to accomplish, but the only thing I can think of is forced adherence to a bad standard. Therefore, I can foresee that you, or the author of CTMShutdownHook, first needs some introspective on how to deal with JVM shutdowns, so that they understand that the idea underlying their implementation is fundamentally misguided and needs to be rethought.

I will do that here.

There is this mindset that to 'properly' shut down a VM, one should never invoke System.exit, one should instead carefully tell all running threads to stop, and one should carefully manage the daemon flag on all threads, so that the VM will end up shutting down on its own volition because all still alive threads have the daemon flag set. The argument being that this gives each thread the chance to 'shut down nicely'.

**This is bad code style.**

Your app will just shut down if someone hits CTRL+C or otherwise asks the VM to exit, this will not result in a nice 'ask all threads to clean up and stop' process. In fact, your app gets zero opportunity to clean up anything if someone trips over a powercable, the computer hard-crashes, or someone terminates the app.

This leads to the following rules:

- Any code that is written so that it *breaks* if not shut down nicely (e.g. you keep some state in memory, and upon being asked to quit, you save this state to disk; it is quite a serious bug if this state is just forgotten) **is bad code**. It is always possible to write code so that recovery is possible. Even extreme cases, such as filesystems, can (these days) handle just pulling the cord using e.g. journalling technology.
- If you want to at least 'be nice' and try to save state or otherwise cleanup, do not wait for someone to tell your thread to 'exit nicely'. Just register a shutdown handler which does the cleanup, and assume your main thread loop will just straight up abort at some arbitrary point without any further notification. This is not actually hard to write.
- Said differently: Don't ever assume your thread will be told to clean up after itself. Assume that usually any registered shutdownhandlers are invoked, but don't rely on them entirely, as in rare scenarios (power pulse, `kill -9`, VM core crash, memory issues, someone runs this in an IDE and just kills it, which is usually a hard-kill, the list is long) those don't run either.

By adding a shutdownhook that 'joins' a thread (joining = pause this thread until that thread exits), you've created a very silly scenario where of the 3 different ways to shut an app down:

- Someone trips over a powercable or kill -9s your app: Everything dies on the spot, no cleanup possible.
- CTRL+C is hit or someone calls System.exit or normal SIGKILLs your app: Everything dies on the spot, but all shutdown hooks are invoked.
- (Misguided) Within the app some process starts trying to get all non-daemon threads to return, and they will presumably be doing their cleanup internally.

What 'join this thread in a shutdown hook' does is effectively downgrade that second form to the (bad) third form.

With that context, you can now fix the broken code in CTMShutdownHook, or talk to the developer of that hook and explain to them that the elegant-sounding idea of allowing *all* running threads to shut down nicely is in fact bad.

Then as a more general point of principle, shutdown hooks should block as little as possible and should definitely not wait for other threads to act.

Comment: Thank you for that elaborate answer. It really helped me understand the concept. Although I disagree on the point that "it is bad to let threads shutdown cleanly". If one of four threads dies, i think the others should still be able to end their tasks and shutdown cleanly (if possible of course)

Comment: > Although I disagree on the point that "it is bad to let threads shutdown cleanly". – It sounds nice, doesn't it? But the real world would like to have a word: It is not that nice. You're advocating for java apps that will fail in extremely annoying ways (having to manually fix databases, lock files, lost data, etc) if you do things like 'terminate app', or if it gets killed by the OS for taking too much memory, etc. It is superior to write java apps that DO deal with it well, and once you have - well, you've already got an app that handles getting their threads shutdown uncleanly.